# EF Migration doesn't specify the migration

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-core

In PM console I enter

```
Update-Database -Migration BookCoverFieldUpdate -StartUpProject Infrastructure
```

But it keep applying InitialMigration. This causes the exception.

```
PM> Update-Database -Migration BookCoverFieldUpdate -StartUpProject Infrastructure
Build started...
Build succeeded.
Applying migration '20230228105846_InitialMigration'.
Failed executing DbCommand (1ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
CREATE TABLE "Authors" (
    "Id" INTEGER NOT NULL CONSTRAINT "PK_Authors" PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    "AuthorName" TEXT NOT NULL,
    "BirthDate" TEXT NOT NULL,
    "DeathDate" TEXT NOT NULL
);
Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException (0x80004005): SQLite Error 1: 'table "Authors" already exists'.
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException.ThrowExceptionForRC(Int32 rc, sqlite3 db)
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.PrepareAndEnumerateStatements(Stopwatch timer)+MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.GetStatements(Stopwatch timer)+MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteDataReader.NextResult()
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.ExecuteReader()
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.MigrationCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(IRelationalConnection connection, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationCommandExecutor.ExecuteNonQuery(IEnumerable`1 migrationCommands, IRelationalConnection connection)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String targetMigration)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabaseImpl(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
SQLite Error 1: 'table "Authors" already exists'.
```

I use SQLite and EF7. How can I fix this?

Comment: The `-Migration` flag is the "target" migration. EF7 will try to apply all migrations (that have not yet been applied according to `_EFMigrationsHistory`) up until & including that migration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check your migration history table. I suspect there is something wrong there, possible causes:

- Someone deleted the entries there, now your database is shot to hell and you need to manually reconstruct that metadata table from your source code.
- This migration didn't fully apply, and did not rollback completely either upon failure. Some objects are now present, yet the migration is missing from the history table causing EF to think it needs to apply those changes again. Yet when it does, some of the objects are already present causing this error.

Comment: It actually was due to migrations history. Record was corrupted.